# How do you reindex Elasticsearch to change the fields of a type?

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I've read this the reindex blog and a slew of SO questions on ES re-indexing, but I'm confused about how you reindex an existing index to change the fields of its type. I've indexed a dataset whose fields may change over the course of time. Does reindex allow me to actually change the fields of my original index (if so how), or do I have to create a second index, reindex the documents in my original index to the second index, and then alias my original index to the second index?

Comment: That's exactly how you described it, you cannot modify an existing index, so you need to create a new one.